# object_mask not working for Ruby SoftLayer API call SoftLayer::BareMetalServer.find_servers

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm having trouble getting an object_mask applied to the data I'm retrieving.  Here is a snippet of what I'm doing:

```
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(<...hidden...>)

<BREAK>

if (item["hostName"])
  machines = SoftLayer::BareMetalServer.find_servers({ :client => client, :hostname => item["hostName"], :object_mask => "[id,hostname,tagReferences]"})

    machines.each do |machine|
    pp machine
  end
end
```

When I print "machine" it is still printing all the fields.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the ojectMask for the method find_servers does not limit the fields, it adds the fields of your object mask to the result.

If you need to limit the fields, you could use the use "map" to create an array with just the fields you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get specific items using masks with “BareMetalServer.find_servers”, but below is another ruby example that may help you:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         :api_key => SL_API_KEY)

account_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Account')

# Create an object mask to get more information than by default
mask = 'mask[id,hostname]'

begin
  result = account_service.object_mask(mask).getHardware
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  p result
rescue Exception => e
  raise e
end
```

**References:**

```
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware    
https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/token_auth/
https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/find_my_vms/
https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/
https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/softlayer_api/2.1.0
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby/blob/master/lib/softlayer/BareMetalServer.rb
```

Comment: Thanks mcruz.  I also have success with other calls such as getHardware.  But this find_servers, although it says it accepts an object_mask option, does not seem to cooperate.